# Pre-deploy development communication with an Internal Kubernetes service

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, vpn

I'm investigating a move to Kubernetes (coming from AWS ECS). But I haven't solved the local development issue when depending on internal services.

Let me elaborate:

When developing and testing microservices, before they are deployed as a Kubernetes Service I want to be able to talk to other, internal Kubernetes Services. As there are > 20 microservices I have a Kubernetes cluster running latest development versions. I can't run a MiniKube.

example:

I'm developing an user-service which needs access to the email service. The Email service is already on Kubernetes and is an internal service.

So before the user-service is deployed I want to be able to talk to the internal email service for dev/testing. I can't make use of K8S nice service discovery env vars.

As we currently already have a VPN up to restrict DEV env to testers/development only, could I use this VPN to provide access to the Kubernetes-Service IP-addresses? I do have Kubernetes DEV-env on the same VPC as the VPN is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deploy your internal services as type `NodePort`, then you can access them over your VPN via that nodePort. NodePorts can be dynamically allocated or you can customize them to be 'static' where they are known by you up front.

When developing an app on your local machine, you can access the dependent service by that NodePort.

As an alternative, you can use `port-forwarding` from kubectl (https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/connecting-to-applications-port-forward/) to forward a pod to your local machine. (Note: This only handles traffic to a pod not a service).

Answer (score 1):

Telepresence (http://telepresence.io) is designed for this scenario, though it presumes developers have kubectl access to the staging/dev cluster.